# Left join counts from second table on three attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join, aggregation

**Note: I do not have write permissions in this DB.**

I have a transaction table where I need to count the number of transactions: DONE

```
SELECT
unique_id, 
journey_files_id, 
version_template_code, 
Count (*) as cnt

FROM [XXX].[dbo].[CampaignResponse]
WHERE version_template_code LIKE '%FPQ%'
AND CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) >='02/01/2020' and CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) <='02/29/2020'

GROUP BY unique_id, journey_files_id, version_template_code ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Now I need to join this view to the second table using unique_id, journey_files_id, version_template_code

CURRENT QUERY NOT WORKING:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM [XXX].[dbo].[EmailSend] a

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    unique_id, 
    journey_files_id, 
    version_template_code, 
    Count (email_action) as cnt

FROM [XXX].[dbo].[CampaignResponse]
WHERE version_template_code LIKE '%FPQ%'
AND CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) >='02/01/2020' and CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) <='02/29/2020'


) b ON a.unique_id = b.unique_id 
    AND a.journey_files_id = b.journey_files_id
    AND a.version_template_code = b.version_template_code

WHERE CAST(a.processed AS DATE) >='02/01/2020' and CAST(a.processed AS DATE) <='02/29/2020'
GROUP BY [id]
  ,a.[unique_id]
  ,a.[journey_files_id]
  ,a.[version_template_code]
  ,[ecrm_template_code]
  ,[lead_type]
  ,[quote_number]
  ,[email]
  ,[company_name]
  ,[sl_code]
  ,[kw_subject_line]
  ,[promo_line]
  ,[headline]
  ,[image_top]
  ,[learn_more]
  ,[tfn]
  ,[subhead_1]
  ,[body_copy_1]
  ,[subhead_2]
  ,[bullet_1]
  ,[offer]
  ,[video_img]
  ,[video_url]
  ,[video_copy]
  ,[legal]
  ,[kw_url_01]
  ,[kw_url_02]
  ,[variable_01]
  ,[variable_02]
  ,[tracking_pixel_url]
  ,[processed]
  ,b.cnt
  ,b.unique_id, b.journey_files_id, b.version_template_code
   ORDER BY b.unique_id
```

Error Message:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Column 'AJM.dbo.CampaignResponse.unique_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Which makes sense - I just can't seem to come up with a work around.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: why are you using `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`?

Comment: You're using the * wildcard to select all columns, but not all columns thereby selected are named in the group by clause. Any column selected but not in the group by clause must have an explicit aggregate applied to it. The * wildcard and the group by clause are not normally combined for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Do grouping in that table only (also edited dates and date range for safety):

```
with b as 
(
SELECT
unique_id, 
journey_files_id, 
version_template_code, 
Count (*) as cnt

FROM [XXX].[dbo].[CampaignResponse]
WHERE version_template_code LIKE '%FPQ%'
AND CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) >='20200201' and CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) < '20200301'

GROUP BY unique_id, journey_files_id, version_template_code
)
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM [XXX].[dbo].[EmailSend] a
LEFT JOIN
 b ON a.unique_id = b.unique_id 
    AND a.journey_files_id = b.journey_files_id
    AND a.version_template_code = b.version_template_code
WHERE CAST(a.processed AS DATE) >='20200201' and CAST(a.processed AS DATE) <'20200301'
   ORDER BY b.unique_id
```

EDIT: Same thing with a subquery if you will:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM [XXX].[dbo].[EmailSend] a
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
unique_id, 
journey_files_id, 
version_template_code, 
Count (*) as cnt

FROM [XXX].[dbo].[CampaignResponse]
WHERE version_template_code LIKE '%FPQ%'
AND CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) >='20200201' and CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) < '20200301'

GROUP BY unique_id, journey_files_id, version_template_code
)
 b ON a.unique_id = b.unique_id 
    AND a.journey_files_id = b.journey_files_id
    AND a.version_template_code = b.version_template_code
WHERE CAST(a.processed AS DATE) >='20200201' and CAST(a.processed AS DATE) <'20200301'
   ORDER BY b.unique_id;
```

Comment: It wasn't allowing me to GROUB BY in my subquery, is it allowing it now because it is now wrapped in a CTE?

Comment: @AmberWilliams, no it would work with a subquery too. I just wanted to make it cleaner. In your case you were trying to group by on the result while your aggregate function was in the subquery. Edited to include subquery version. It is same, CTE version is more readable.

Comment: I get it now!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `group by` outside the inner query since you're not calculating any aggregate values outside. You just need a simple `left join` as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM [XXX].[dbo].[EmailSend] a
left join (SELECT
unique_id, 
journey_files_id, 
version_template_code, 
Count (*) as cnt
FROM [XXX].[dbo].[CampaignResponse]
WHERE version_template_code LIKE '%FPQ%'
AND CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) >='02/01/2020' and CAST(email_action_date AS DATE) <='02/29/2020'
GROUP BY unique_id, journey_files_id, version_template_code) b
ON a.unique_id = b.unique_id AND a.journey_files_id = b.journey_files_id AND a.version_template_code = b.version_template_code 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Completion time: 2020-03-16T14:42:01.5149991-05:00

Comment: I moved `order by` outside the inner query. Can you see if it works now?